# Any ideas why woocommerce redirect to 404 message?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Any idea why my woocommerce shop redirect to the following URL: http://website.com/checkout/order-received/092/?key=order_53278f779fde2 instead of: http://website.com/checkout/order-received/ ?

I would love a redirect function that can do that. here is what I am thinking:

```
add_function_woocommerce_redirect_url_something
```

I have also tried to change the permalinks with no luck!!

Comment: Did you set up the "Thank You" page with the shortcode and select it in the woocommerce settings page?

Comment: Yes I did and everything looks fine but the 404 error is strange!!!

Comment: I fixed it Thank you! It was a payment plugin redirect issue! Thank you

Comment: That's great. And I think you should give the explanation of your problem and how did you solved it for future reference, in case anyone need that.

Comment: Sure! The issue was not related to woocommerce it was related to the payment gateway. I had to find the line: `'redirect'  => get_site_url().'/checkout/order-received/'.$order->id.'/?key='.$order->order_key );` and basically fix it and change it with the followings: ` 'redirect'  => get_site_url().'/thank-you-order/' );`

Answer (score 0):

```
add_filter('woocommerce_get_checkout_order_received_url','my_order_received_url',0,2);
function my_order_received_url($return_url,$order){
    $return_url = str_replace('?','&',$return_url);
    $return_url = str_replace('/order-received/','/?order-received=',$return_url);
    return $return_url;
}
```

Comment: Please add some text to explain what this code does and maybe how it does.

Answer (score 0):

```
add_filter('woocommerce_get_checkout_order_received_url','my_order_received_url',0,2);
function my_order_received_url($return_url, $order){
    if( preg_match('~/order\-received/\d+\?~', $return_url) ){
        $return_url = str_replace('?','&',$return_url);
        $return_url = str_replace('/order-received/','/?order-received=',$return_url);
    }
    return $return_url;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check also Pages -> Checkout page if is published.
**
The page was Draft and that was the problem.